# Achar menor string de uma lista em python

Tags: python

como faço uma função para determinar a menor string em uma lista ingnorando espaços?

Por exemplo, ao digitar:

```
menor_elemento(["joão", "   a ", "arrozz"])
```

a saída deve retornar "a" (sem espaços), pois é a menor string (ingnorando os espaços).

Aqui está o código que tentei:

```
def menor_nome(nome):
    m = min(nome)
    m = m.strip
    return m
```

Comment: A saída deve retornar apenas o caractere `a` ou o valor real na lista incluindo os espaços em branco?

Comment: a saída deve retornar somente {a}

Comment: Pode [edit] a pergunta e adicionar o código que tentou fazer?

Comment: sem espaços, e sem os parenteses

Comment: claro, eu edito agora

Comment: trabalho concluído amigo, editei a pergunta! Veja se está melhor

Comment: Só faltou os `()` na chamada do método `strip`. Coloque-os e deve funcionar.

Comment: ok, já o fiz. Muito obrigado

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60236/discussion-between-d-fritoti-and-anderson-carlos-woss).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Editada (Nova versão): 
>   Na realidade minha versão original esta totalmente errada, não atentei para o fato de que o que a pergunta solicita é o menor "tamanho" da string e não o menor valor. Como também percebi que a outra reposta também não estava totalmente correta, uma vez que não levava em consideração o decode das strings e nem quando existem mais de duas strings com o tamanho igual ao mínimo, resolvi fazer uma nova versão.

Obs. Obviamente considerei que a lista tenha sempre o mesmo tipo de dado, no caso strings, pois não faria sentido a mistrura de strings e numéricos nesse contexto. Para numérico seria bem fácil adaptar o codigo, lá vai:

[DEMO](https://repl.it/IfeV/1)

```
import unicodedata as ud

def min_list(_list_str):
    # Tamanho da lista
    len_list = len(_list_str)

    # Normalizando a lista (suprimindo acentos)
    list_str =  [  (ud.normalize('NFKD', s ).encode('ASCII','ignore').decode()).strip() for s in  _list_str]

    # Produz uma lista com os tamanhos de cada elemento
    lens = [len(s) for s in list_str]

    # Tamanho do menor (ou menores, quando empate) elemento
    min_len = min(lens)

    # Lista para guardar as strings cujos tamanhos sejam iguais ao minimo
    mins = []

    for i in range(len_list):
        # String normalizada
        s = list_str[i]
        if len(s)==min_len:
            mins.append(_list_str[i].strip() )

    return mins  


list_str = ['maria', 'josé', 'PAULO', 'Catarina]', ' kate  ', 'joão', 'mara' ]


print ( min_list(list_str) )
['josé', 'kate', 'joão', 'mara']
```

[Veja o código funcionano aqui.](https://repl.it/IfeV/1)

---

> Versão original

```
min(["joão", "   a ", "arrozz"]).strip()
'a'
```

:-)

Comment: muito obrigado amigo! Quebrou um galho

Comment: Dê o aceite e o upvote, please. :-)

Comment: Obrigado pelo feedback! Votos de usuários com menos de 15 de reputação reputação são registrados, mas não mudam a pontuação mostrada no post.

não tenho como, perdão. Mas dei o "aceite"

Comment: Verdade, esqueci disso. Valeu.

Comment: cara só uma observação ao seu código.

Comment: ao digitar a seguinte lista: ['maria', 'josé', 'PAULO', 'Catarina']. O resultado esperado seria josé, contudo obtive catarina

Comment: sabes como proceder para que a saída seja josé?

Comment: Ok, na verdade estou vendo que nem a minha resposta e nem a outro estão totalmente corretas, vou edita-la para uma nova versão.

Comment: Após a edição da ultima versao percebi que havia esquecido o strip(), corrigi.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60245/discussion-between-d-fritoti-and-sidon).

Answer (score 2):

A função min retornará o menor elemento da lista. Entretanto, é preciso considerar o tipo dos elementos na lista. No caso de números, o menor número.

```
print('Exemplo 1')
menor = min([3, 4, 2, 1])
print(menor)

Out[]: Exemplo 1
Out[]: 1
```

No caso de uma string, ele retornará o menor considerando a ordem alfabética.
E entenda que o espaço vem antes do a. Dessa forma, o espaço precisa ser removido antes para que a ordenação da função retorne o resultado que você espera. Mudei um pouco o seu array para você entender o problema. No exemplo 2, você espera que o resultado seja "a", mas o retorno é "   arrozz   ".

```
print('Exemplo 2')
menor = min(["joão", "   b   ", "   arrozz   ", "a"])
print(menor.strip())

Out[]: Exemplo 2
Out[]: arrozz
```

Para ter o resultado esperado, utilize o parametro key passando uma função lambda que fará o strip para cada elemento.

```
print('Exemplo 3')
menor = min(["joão", "   b   ", "   arrozz   ", "a"], key=lambda x: x.strip())
print(menor.strip())

Out[]: Exemplo 3
Out[]: a
```

Se o que você precisa é a string com o menor número de caracteres ignorando os espaços, utilize a função lambda abaixo. Ela retornará o tamanho de cada string (sem os espaços) para ser avaliado pela função min.

```
print('Exemplo 4')
menor = min(["joão", "   b   ", "   arrozz   ", "a"], key=lambda x: len(x.strip()))
print(menor.strip())

Out[]: Exemplo 4
Out[]: b
```

Comment: obrigado, amigo. A melhor resposta e melhor explicada

Answer (score -2):

```
#Pede pro usuario digitar uma lista que deve ter seus itens separados 
por espaços e adiciona cada um deles a lista com o split()

#Imprime a lista na tela, mostrando qual a menor string presente na lista

lista = input("Digite uma lista: ").split()
print (min(lista, key=len))
```

Comment: Essa solução não atende 100% ao que foi perguntado pois não desconsidera os espaços em branco. Consegue adaptar a resposta para adicionar esse detalhe na implementação? Vale também o exercício de validar se o mesmo já não foi respondido em outras respostas.